# Outlook Web-App with React, NPM and Debug

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, reactjs, office365, outlook-addin

I want start to implement an Outlook 365 Web Add-In.
After all, I decided to create it with React.

I already tried to set up some project's but all of them have a lot disadvantages:

**Visual Studio 2017 Office 365 Outlook Project:**

Pro:

- Client debugging support (quite important)

Con:

- As it's a Web-Project, hosted by IIS, I cannot work with NPM (YARN) and Webpack (without lot of frustration) and compile ES6, JSX code to ES5 and debug that stuff

**Visual Studio Code:**

Pro:

- Node and NPM Support
- Can easily work with React and ES6/7/JSX

Contra:

- No debugging support for client side

---

**Question**

However MS has written in it's own documentation that till this day we're unable to debug JS-Code with Visual Studio Code in Outlook, is there maybe an comfortable alternative to do it?

I don't want to give up work with React and ES6 so is there a way to do it with VS-Web Projects and IIS?

What is in your opinion the best work flow for my needs?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

There is a middle ground where you can use VS Code but still have decent (albeit not quite as tightly integrated as in VS debugging).  The trick is just to make sure that you *have* Visual Studio, but it needn't be a VS project that you are debugging:

If you are on **Outlook for PC / Desktop**:  See https://dev.office.com/blogs/attach-debugger-from-the-task-pane.  The article shows you how to attach in the context of Word, but the same applies to Outlook (and instead of using the "Personality Menu", you can just right-click and see the same "attach debugger" option).

[image: Right-click menu]

If you are debugging a **web version of Outlook,** that's even easier:  just open up your browser's F12 tools.

Hope this helps!